# Should I notify the author to avoid duplicate effort for the same work?

Tags: github

I recently got aware that someone on Github is trying to build an image labeling tool that I already have developed 2 years back. His work is in the initial stage currently. But got good popularity. Other than a few features which are not developed yet but in his roadmap and not present in my code yet, we have the same goal.

Should I suggest him to not waste his effort and to join the project that I have already built?

Comment: Are these tools in the same language? Are the implementations themselves similar?

Comment: Yes in html,css,js/typescript

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are many reasons to develop open source software – not only to create some necessary tool, but sometimes also just to *build* something. So this is not necessarily a case of *wasted* effort. Phrasing it like that would  be highly disrespectful.

For sure, pointing them to your existing project would be a nice thing to do. Maybe you can get inspiration from their code, or they can incorporate some of your components. I closely watch “competing” open source projects, and point users to them if my project doesn't have some feature that they need.

But do not expect the projects to somehow merge. Open source is not a competition, and nobody wins or loses. Everybody wins if you cooperate, but nothing is lost if you don't. Instead of suggesting that all development concentrates on one of the projects, you might instead be able to identify some components that can be shared and maintained together.